# Slow response with symfony

Tags: json, api, symfony, heroku

I have a symfony app (2.8.28) hosted in heroku and I can monitoring request with NewRelic and I realize that there some requests that are really slow and it is a really simple request which gets the API version and returned it in JSON format and sometimes it takes around 20 seconds ( sometimes), most of the times works really fast)

More in detail.

**Controller**

```
private $apiVersion;

public function __construct($apiVersion) {
    $this->apiVersion = $apiVersion;
}

/**
 * @Route("", name="api_version_index", defaults={"_format": "json"})
 */
public function indexAction() {
    return new JsonResponse(
        ['version' => $this->apiVersion]
    );
}
```

**Controller.yml**

```
services:
    controller.api.version:
        class: NewsBundle\Controller\Api\VersionController
        arguments:
            - %api_version%
```

**parameters.yml**

```
api_version: 2
```

And the captures from NewRelic which show the slow response:

[image: Tracking slow response]

[image: Sometimes there are slow responses]

Comment: This look like you cache is really big and it's removed "sometimes" without a cache warm-up, but the `Remainder` thing (unrelated to Symfony I guess) has the major time, so requires special attention.

Comment: [Show us the trace details](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/exact-meaning-and-strategy-for-remainder/8303/4) so we can see what "Remainder" is doing. (replace the existing image you have of the trace with an image of the trace details, please)

Comment: I didn't realize about this tab in new relic is really helpful to understand what is happening, thank you. 

I just add the image in the question.

Comment: Checking trace details I realized that is a "common problem" loading dependencies with composer, I find other question that is exactly what is happening to me but there is not response.